# What's the term when variables "express"?

Tags: terminology

I'm writing up explanatory variables and searching for a general term that collectively describes whether variables "express." E.g., comparing the performance of athletes on occasions when they are booed. Would booed be the "expression" of an explanatory variable? Or, maybe, "presence" of an explanatory variable? "Active"?

Comment: Perhaps compare those booed and those not booed, or talk about whether booing occurred or took place or was observed or was reported. I think this is more about general English style in technical writing than about specialised statistical terminology, but none the worse for that.

Comment: Agreed @Nick. When I'm talking about specific variables, I discuss as you proposed. In one paragraph in my discussion I hypothesize about variables future researchers may collect, so I don't know what the verb (e.g., booed) of the variable would be, which is why I was searching for a general term. I don't have a stats background and know these terms can be loaded, which is why I want to be careful about using "expressed" (or any other term).

Comment: I find it hard to advise in generality. Sometimes people have predictors that really are causal, but more often predictors are proxy more or less indirectly for influences or circumstances that one way or another may help in prediction. Appropriate language will vary accordingly.

Comment: One universal usage is: variables have *values.*

Comment: *Express* seems more a synonym for *measurement* to me.

Comment: Other comments lead me to a better understanding of the question. "encode" is another possibility.

Comment: I came across the term "exposure" on wikipedia's "spurious relationship" page (in the page's figure). Could I say, "Extending the present findings, future studies may find performance decreases in athletes exposed to similar variables."